# Why images are not showing in slide show mode Ms PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow, bug

When I insert an image in the slide , it is visible in the preview and editor mode but not in slide show mode.

I am using a Lenovo tab 4 8 .

I am also part of office insider program but I don't think that this should affect it.

I used design Ideas feature as well , just in case you need this information.

Attaching screenshot for reference.

[![Editor mode[[image: ][1]]

[image: Slide show mode]

[image: Editor mode]

[image: Slide show mode]

Here is the link if you want to try it at your end [Here is the ppt](https://1drv.ms/p/s!As9Ilu0P6r_JhDKJJWul6UDHShMN)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Doesn't happen with Office365. Which version of PowerPoint? Do you by "slide show mode" mean the one started with F5?

Comment: As with @harrymc, I'm seeing the images in slide show view both in the web version of PPT and on the desktop, Office 365. Do you or a colleague have another PC with a non-Insider version of Office to test the presentation with? Also, try starting PowerPoint in Safe Mode before viewing the slide show. Start PPT by holding down SHIFT as you double click PowerPoint's icon (not a PPTX file's icon), then answer YES when it asks if you'd like to start in Safe Mode.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg The problem was with my device it's working now. Thank you

Comment: @MohdSaad Glad to hear it. For the benefit of others who might run into the same problem, please let us know what exactly the problem was and how you fixed it. In fact, explain that in an answer rather than a comment. You're allowed to answer your own questions!

Comment: It works fine in PowerPoint online, what version of PowerPoint are you using?

Comment: @Lee problem was with my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution. The problem was with my device.

You can use PowerPoint online or you can clear the data of the app and sign in again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).